# Pytorch Geometric Datasets

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, dataset, pytorch-geometric

I need your help. I have two set of graph structured data, one from Open Graph Benchmark (OGB) and another created with [`torch_geometric.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data.html#torch_geometric.data.Dataset) from my own data . The data looks like:

> Data(edge_index=[2, 88], edge_attr=[88, 3], x=[39, 9], y=[1, 1])  #OGB

> Data(x=[23, 9], edge_index=[2, 48], edge_attr=[48, 2], y=[1]) #PyG

I am trying to use a framework developed using OGB functions, this doesn't work with data created using PyG. For example: the first part of the framework load and split the dataset into train, val and test:

```
# Set the random seed
random.seed(random_seed)
np.random.seed(random_seed)

# Create data loaders
split_idx = dataset.get_idx_split() # train/val/test split
loader_dict = {}
for phase in split_idx:
    batch_size = 32
    loader_dict[phase] = DataLoader(dataset[split_idx[phase]], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

When I run this code with a native ogb dataset I have no problems, when I use the PyG data return the error:

> AttributeError

This is strange because they are both Pytorch objects, the only difference is that the OGB dataset is an InMemoryDataset and the PyG one is a 'Larger' dataset (https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_dataset.html). Is there any way to fix this without having to change the source code?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you state one of the OGB functions you want to use and include the full error trace you get when you use the function with your own dataset?

Comment: @Sparky05 Sure, I edited the post and added more details

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same code, you need to implement `get_idx_split` for your own dataset.
You can find the desired return structure in the OGB GitHub, e.g. [here](https://github.com/snap-stanford/ogb/blob/master/ogb/nodeproppred/dataset.py#L142):

```
def get_idx_split(self):
    < ... do something to retrieve train/test/validation set>
    return {'train': train_idx, 'valid': valid_idx, 'test': test_idx}
```